# SQL Server - Error when update a INT field with a FLOAT value. Value change

Tags: sql-server, int, sql-update, converters, precision

I have a problem when I update a integer variable with a float value. The value '100' changes to '99' when it is updated.

```
DECLARE @intResultado INTEGER=NULL
DECLARE @dblResultado FLOAT=NULL
DECLARE @dblValorMercado FLOAT =15700123654.8047
DECLARE @intCambioTasaInteres INTEGER=100

SET @intResultado=SUM(@dblValorMercado * @intCambioTasaInteres) / SUM(CASE WHEN @dblValorMercado = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @dblValorMercado END)
SET @dblResultado=SUM(@dblValorMercado * @intCambioTasaInteres) / SUM(CASE WHEN @dblValorMercado = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @dblValorMercado END)

SELECT '1. Operation result =' AS [Result], SUM(@dblValorMercado * @intCambioTasaInteres) / SUM(CASE WHEN @dblValorMercado = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @dblValorMercado END) AS [Operation], 'GOOD' AS EVAL
UNION
SELECT '2. Integer operation result  =',@intResultado, 'BAD'
UNION
SELECT '3. Float operation result = ',@dblResultado, 'GOOD'
```

This is the result:

```
Result                         Operation              EVAL
------------------------------ ---------------------- ----
1. Original operation result = 100                    GOOD
2. Integer operation result  = 99                     BAD
3. Float operation result =    100                    GOOD

(3 row(s) affected)
```

The calculation made is a "sum of weighted averages", which in this case corresponds to only 1 value (100 in this case), but that could be n values that would be used to perform the sum of weighted averages.

The problem could be solved by changing the INT variable to a FLOAT variable, but that is not the idea. But to detect why the value 100 at the time of updating becomes a value of 99 and how to do so that the correct value 100 is updated with the INT variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the SQL engine is trying to cast prior to finishing the arithmetic. See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-data-conversion-horribly-wrong/ section 3: Assuming all numbers are created equal

Note that when he assigns a DECIMAL to an INT variable, it FLOOR's the value.

These two statements also produce 99:

```
SELECT CONVERT( INT, (@dblValorMercado * @intCambioTasaInteres) / @dblValorMercado )
SELECT FLOOR( (@dblValorMercado * @intCambioTasaInteres) / @dblValorMercado )
```

While, as you've pointed out, the following produces 100:

```
SELECT (@dblValorMercado * @intCambioTasaInteres) / @dblValorMercado
```

In C# there are similar issues converting float to int. (https://answers.unity.com/questions/701483/float-to-int-conversion-using-int-gives-wrong-answ.html)